# How do I get multimonth plugin of the jQuery datePicker to load with certain dates already selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

well im using this script right here:
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/

and I have a multiMonth plugin and multiple select enabled.

I want to be able to on load have certain dates already selected and those dates come from a database
I found two possible clues to help me out, but since I have not strictly learned JS yet, I can not made heads or tails.
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/renderCalendarBankHolidays.html
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerDefaultToday.html

here's the code right now im using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   jQuery(function() {
      jQuery('#multimonth').datePickerMultiMonth({
         numMonths: 12,
         inline: true,
         selectMultiple: true,
         startDate: '01/09/2009', // DD/MM/YY
         month: 8, // 0=JAN  1=FEB ...
         year: 2009
      }).bind(
         'dpMonthChanged',
         function(event, displayedMonth, displayedYear) {
          //uncomment if you have firebug and want to confirm this works as expected...
          //console.log('dpMonthChanged', arguments);
      }).bind(
         'dateSelected',
         function(event, date, jQuerytd, status) {
         //uncomment if you have firebug and want to confirm this works as expected...
         //console.log('dateSelected', arguments);
      }).val(
         new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
      jQuery('#getSelected').bind(
         'click',
         function(e) {
            alert(jQuery('#multimonth').dpmmGetSelected());
            return false;
      });
   });
</script>
```

and this part is not being selected, I took it from the select todays date demo

```
.val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example demonstrates exactly what you are trying to do:

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiMonth5.html